# Access to resource missing with an exported jar file

Tags: java, jar, resources

If I run the following code within eclipse my program compiles with no issue.  If I try to export the program as a runnable jar file my resource cannot be found.

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
  
      File file = new File(Tester.class.getClassLoader().getResource("res/myFile.txt").getFile());

      if(!file.exists()) { System.out.println("File not found."); }
   }

}
```

Folder structure (by running `jar tf test.jar`):

> com/
>
> com/test/
>
> com/test/Tester.class
>
> res/
>
> res/myFile.txt

Comment: Please show us your folder structire. Is the File included in you jar?

Comment: @Jens yes the file is included in the jar.  I opened it to double check.

Comment: and it is under a folder `res`?

Comment: @Jens correct... as I mentioned it runs fine in eclipse, just not as a jar.

Comment: Look at my answer. I guess you need a "/" in front of res. If not show us the directory structure in you jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such file in case of jar.

Use instead `Tester.class.getResourceAsStream("/myFile.txt")` and work with the stream

UPDATE:
See more [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-getresourceasstream-in-static-method/) or [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/classloader_getresourceasstream.htm)

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why I can't get the file using the method above via the executable jar?

Comment: You can't. There is no such file. There is something inside jar file and FileSystem can't access the inner part of file (in fact jar is a zip archive). But java provides the way to access to jar file content via reasource streams.